# Need your assistance to correct the sentence

Tags: british-english

Need your assistance to correct the sentence which I will send it my boss .

> customer was charged by mistake 50 dollar for replacing his card
>   please approve to reverse it

Answer (score 2):

> Our customer was erroneously charged $50 for credit card replacement.
>   Please approve the charge reversal. Thank you.

If you need to ask permission or if you made an error, then you might need to say this differently.  And you of course need to add in the customer's name as it appears on the account, the account number, and the date the error happened.

> I made an error and charged our customer John Doe, $50 for credit card  replacement on 1/14/17. This concerns account number 123 456 7890.
>   Would it be possible for you to/Would you please/Please reverse the charge for me and the customer(?).   Thank you.

Comment: @hap hap You do know that the **/** means you select from one of these?